# Position of while loop for numpy array

Tags: arrays, for-loop, numpy, while-loop

I want to have a 6 by 12 matrix and:

1- arrange numbers 1-12 in 6 rows, with no repeat in each row, and no repeat in columns pairs 1,2 - 3,4 ... 11-12.

2- If (i,j) occurs in columns pair (1,2), (i,j) or (j,i) should not occur in the other columns pair (i.e. columns (3,4), (5,6)...)

This is what I achieved so far:

```
arr = np.zeros((6,12))
arr[0,:] = np.random.choice((range(1,13)),12,replace=False)
for row in range(1,6):     
    for i in range(0,12,2):
        counter = 0
        n=np.random.randint(1,13)
        while ((n in arr[:,i]) or (n in arr[:,i+1]) or (n in (arr[row,:]))):
            n=np.random.randint(1,13)
            counter += 1
            if counter>100:
                print 'ERROR!', 'row',row, 'i',i
                break
        arr[row,i]=n

    for i in range(1,12,2):
        counter = 0                
        n=np.random.randint(1,13)
        while ((n in arr[:,i]) or (n in arr[:,i-1]) or (n in (arr[row,:]))):
            n=np.random.randint(1,13)
            counter += 1
            if counter>100:
                print 'ERROR!', 'row', row, 'i', i
                break
        arr[row,i]=n
    print arr

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

The correct output should be like this:

```
3     7    11     8    10    12     6     1     2     4     9     5
11     4    12     5     6     8     3     9    10     7     2     1
 5     2     1     3    11     9     4    10     8    12     6     7
 6    10     9     7     2     3     8     5    11     1     4    12
12     9     6     4     1     7    11     2     3     5     8    10
 8     1    10     2     4     5    12     7     9     6    11     3
```

The success of the code depends on the first guess for row 1. I believe I need to make a while loop, so that when ERROR! occurs, the code resets row and i, and restarts from the third line.

Can anyone help please, on where the while loop should be set?

Thanks.